# p:selectCheckboxMenu highlight list item when mouse is over an item

Tags: css, primefaces

I know p:selectCheckboxMenu has all its style classes, but i want to change something.
I would want that when i open the menu and move with the mouse over an item, it will be highlighted in blue. I want it to be highlighted only when the mouse is over that item.

i think that the css class i need to override is : `.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-item` which means

> Each options in the collection.

(from the primefaces 5.0 documentation)

I am kind of a novice in css....any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe not what you"d like to hear, but a tutorial to leave being a novice behind you is the best suggestion I can give

Comment: Youre absolutly right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:hover` pseudo-selector.
If `.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-item` select the elements that you want to highlight, then with this code should work:

```
.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-item:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}
```